# Need to link each image in this slideshow to a different page on my site.

Tags: html, hyperlink, slideshow

I am trying to link each picture/slide to a certain page on my site and am having no luck whatsoever. I have looked around and haven't been able to find an answer that works. This slideshow works amazing as is, but I want to make it more interactive and am at a loss as to how to achieve what I want.

```
<style type="text/css">
.jj {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div align="center"></div>
<table width="1080" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#404040"><table width="1080" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="jj"><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="Images/abouthome.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="Images/instructhome.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="Images/awardhome.jpg"
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.fasda {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="fasda">
<img src="Images/abouthome.jpg" name="slide" width=1080 height=400>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<10)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",6000)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script></td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
```

The slide show works great, but I am at a complete loss as to how I would go about linking each of these slides to a specific page on my site. Please help!! 
Thanks!

Comment: you should also tag this as `javacript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wrapping the image with <a></a>:

```
<a id="thelink"><img src="Images/abouthome.jpg" name="slide" width=1080 height=400></a>
```

And then above when you declare the image variables, declare your page URLS:

```
 var links = ["http://www.example.com/page1", "http://www.example.com/pae2"];
```

And then in the slideit() function, add the link:

```
document.getElementById("thelink").setAttribute("href", links[step]);
```